# Unable to start beanstalkd after the installation

Tags: beanstalkd

After the installation of beanstalkd on my ubuntu 13.04

I run "`beanstalkd -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11300`" command to start it

CLI returned:

```
beanstalkd: net.c:119 in make_server_socket: bind(): Address already in use
beanstalkd: main.c:64 in main: make_server_socket()
```

Please what can i do? i'm new to this queue system.

Comment: "Address already in use" means you already have a copy of it running. Look for it with "pgrep -lf beanstalkd" and kill it, if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't found process as mention by @Alister Bulman

Maybe some other service is using port 11300
Try to start with another port

ex:

```
beanstalkd -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11345
```